# iPhone style news symbol with localstorage/cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

On the site that I'm working on I have a blog-page. When i add a new post to the blog i want to add a symbol on the link in the main menu to the blog. When the link is clicked i want to use localstorage or set a cookie that makes the symbol disappear.

Kind of like how the symbol works on iPhone when there is news in an app, the red circle with a number in it.

My problem is that i havnt been working with this kind of code much so i dont know which code to use. Should i set a cookie or is it better to use localStorage? If i should use localStorage, can you give me an example of how the code can look like?

I'm going to set the code manually every time i add a new post so i dont need an automatic code that checks for updates.

Something like

```js
$('#blogLink').click(function(){
  // Set localStorage/Cookie
});

if (localStorage/Cookie) {
  $("#newsSymbol").hide();
}
```

Here is an image to show how i mean:

[See example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCyh2.jpg)

I hope someone can help me with this little problem :) Thank you in advance!

Comment: FYI those UI elements are called 'badges' in iOS. It may help you when googling for a solution.